# HTML font rendering incorrect, can anyone help me to identify why my code is rendering incorrect font

Tags: javascript, html, css

[*enter image description here*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pascS.png)

[This is the snapshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR1cH.png)

Comment: Font might be correct. Character might be incorrect.

Comment: Welcome! Please read the documentation about what a good SO question needs: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in the head of your document?

Are you able to share any code?

Comment: Yes I am using meta tag, not sure but it seems like a browser issue